# Запустить переход по ссылке (вызов события)

Tags: jquery

Есть ссылка

`<a id="67" href="http://example.com">ссылка</a>`

пытаюсь перейти по ней при помощи вызова trigger с передачей идентификатора набирая его с клавиатуры.

`$("#" + pressed).trigger("click");`

но не срабатывает.

[Здесь](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F) нашел, что

> Надо отметить, что вызов события методом trigger() не полностью повторяет событие, произошедшее по естественным причинам. Например вызов события "click" применительно к ссылке, не приведет к переходу по ней.

Подскажите, чем можно запустить переход по ссылке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.location.href = $("#" + pressed).attr('href');
```